# PDF in main viewer instead of new window

Tags: viewers

Since I re-installed LaTeX a while ago, when I click "View PDF" (in Dutch: Bekijk PDF, don't really know if it's "View PDF" in the English version of LaTeX), a new window opens.
However, I'd like the pdf to appear in the main LaTeX-window, as was before I re-installed it.

Can someone help me on this one?

Thanks.

M.

Comment: You can't be doing this in LaTeX because LaTeX is not the kind of thing which has buttons you can click. I assume you are doing this in an editor of some sort but you don't say which one so people are going to find it difficult to help. Which editor are you using? Which PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: I'm using TeXMaker

Comment: Go to Options menu and then Configure. There you can choose to use embedded viewer. http://i.stack.imgur.com/CORiC.png

Comment: @MichaëlHenrotte, it is not necessary. Sometimes the comments are really self explanatory. Or you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 4):

Go to *Options* menu and then *Configure*.

There we can choose to use embedded viewer.

Below we can see the *Embed* option activated.

[image]